# Mongodb Realm - read only access data

Tags: mongodb, authentication, realm

I develop an app with some public information for non logged user.

I am using Mongodb Realm as serverless that need to use Anonymous provider to access data.

How can I set "read only" access to anonymous ? (as it was non logged user)

Comment: *I am using Mongodb Realm as serverless* - does that mean data is stored locally, on the users device only? If that's the case what is the need to Anonymous  authentication?

Comment: Datas are stored inside mongodb atlas, and I access those datas with mongodb Realm (ex stitch). 
Mongodb Realm required logged user to request. I found out that I can use "apply_when" in Realm UI https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/_images/collection-rules-convert-to-advanced-mode.png
but how can I say "anonymous" user are not allowed ?

Answer (score 1):

ok I found out a solution.
Inside "apply_when" condition you can call a boolean function :

```
{
  "%%false": {
    "%function": {
      "name": "isAnonymous"
    }
  }
}
```

and in my case an anonymous has no email, so `isAnonymous` function looks like :

```
exports = function(){
  return !context.user.data.email;
};
```

it seems to work as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it appears the question is

> how can I say "anonymous" user are not allowed ?

That can be done by turning off Anonymous Authentication in the MongoDB Realm console settings for your app.

[image]

Comment: no no, I want anonymous has "read only" access. So I can't disable the provider.